# RegExp get attributes but not the tag name

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get attributes from a JavaScript String with RegExp but I've a last problem.

I can get attributes with or without values, I can get attributes if space between them is forgotten but my RegExp also get the tag name as an attribute.

Live example:
http://regex101.com/r/zX5dJ7/3

the regexp: `(\s*\w+(?:=\"[^\"]*(?:\")?)?)`

example html: `<div name="value"otherattribute foo="bar/>`

Is there a way to ask the RegExp to avoid the tag name ?

**EDIT:**

If the HTML is this:

`<meta charset="utf-8" alone foo="tab"/>
<meta charset2="utf-8"foo2="tab"/>
<meta charset3="utf-8"alone2 foo3="tab unclosed/>`

I want to catch every attributes like this:

1. charset="utf-8",
2. alone,
3. foo="tab",
4. charset2="utf-8",
5. foo2="tab",
6. charset3="utf-8",
7. alone2,
8. foo3="tab unclosed/>

My previous RegExp work well but she catch the tag name, I just want to make the regexp avoid tag name.

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/zX5dJ7/4 . See the captured group at right side.

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid to get the tag name (meta in the live example) but with your solution the attribute "alone" isnt catch.

Comment: Please post your example input and your desired output in the question itself. How should foo3="tab unclosed be returned?

Comment: It seems like your test `html` is purposefully malfromed, perhaps to check for cases where it isn't properly formatted? Even a browser would have issues parsing some of these tags, I don't see how a regex helps from within javascript. In any case, arbitrarily malformed input is hard to deal with in javascript regex, especially since we have no lookbehind. As far as how to handle properly formatted html goes, I think the answers are sufficient and any regex will be a lot simpler to make and use if the html can be assumed to be properly formatted.

Comment: Yes, I know that the html must be correctly formatted to make the regexp more efficient. But its only to highlight text (attributes) in string. If the html is malformed, just try to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with:

```
([<\w\-]+(?:=)?(?:"|')?[\w\-]+(?:"|')?)
```

You will have to skip matches that begin with `<` after using the regex.

*DEMO:* http://regex101.com/r/aL1sQ0/1

**Edit:** Final solution by Jordan himself: `(?:<\w+)?(\s*\w+(?:=\"[^\"]*(?:\")?)?)?`

Comment: You could combine this with the solution of trainoasis. Use his regex to get the tags without the tag names and then use mine to get the attributes from them.

Comment: Ah ! I'va a new version, I combine the @trainoasis has you said, now, the problem is a quite smallest, the last character of the tag name is catch if the tag name is the last thing of the string.
Demo: http://regex101.com/r/zX5dJ7/8

Comment: I finally found this solution. If you see something wrong or a better solution, I take.
Demo: http://regex101.com/r/vA6hO5/1

Comment: Nice. However your 8. example match in you original question does not match the way you probably want it to. Or does it?

Comment: The 8 example correctly catch attributes as group avoiding tagname, its good for me.

Comment: Ok. I included your solution into my answers, just in case someone misses your comment or regex101 ceases to exist. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get everything in between certain TAG and its CLOSING you could use

```
(?:<\w*)(.*)\/>
```

Then you can extract whatever you want from in between. If you need further info let me know

Answer (score 0):

Assuming properly formatted HTML (see my comment in the OP of why we **should** assumed formatted HTML), this regex will parse everything you want and will even allow a "<" in the tag name so you can easily get rid of the tag and know what's a tag and what isn't

`(\w+(=\".*?\"|)|<\w+)`

and [in action](http://regex101.com/r/eX0yU6/2)

Parsing randomly malformed HTML is really *NOT* a job for regex. I cite here the countless cries of pain of many a regexper when they get asked the question of "How can I parse HTML with regular expressions?". Search stackoverflow for such questions and see what people answer. You'll see *exactly* why we should assume non-malformed HTML.

As stated above, after you get your matches and put them in an array or something, you can check for any string that starts with "<" and you'll know its a tag - the rest of the attributes are captured along with their contents, so no worries there.

Comment: My answer on @Jenny O'Reilly is near of what I need.
See this example regex101.com/r/zX5dJ7/8
The only problem is that the regexp catche the last character of '<div'. The "v" character is catch and I dont want that.